# A radio button calls a javascript function to show an input tag before form submission. After the same function fails to show the same input tag

Tags: php, html

The javascript code works on the first call to show an input tag

```
function selbustbla(k)
{
if(k == 1)
{
 document.getElementById("bustbl1").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("bustbl11").style.display = "block";
 }
 if(k == 2)
 {
 document.getElementById("bustbl1").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("bustbl11").style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

The form and radio buttons calling the javascript.  One call is ok.  After submission the same function fails to show the input tag.

```
<form id="frm1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST" >
<table>
<tr><td name="registration" id="registration"><strong>Register </strong></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="rdo" id="aupair" onclick="selbustbla(2)" value="aupair" <? if(isset($_POST['rdo']) && $_POST['rdo'] == 'aupair') echo "checked"; ?> />First</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="rdo" id="babysitter" onclick="selbustbla(1)" value="babysitter" <? if(isset($_POST['rdo']) && $_POST['rdo'] == 'babysitter') echo "checked";?> />Second</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id="bustbl1" name="bustbl1" style="display:none" >
<tr>
<td name="personal" id="personal" ><strong>Personal </strong>details</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Title:&nbsp;</td>           
<td><input id = 'inputtitle' name = 'inputtitle' size = '4' maxlength = '4' type = 'text'></td></tr></table>
<table id="bustbl11" name="bustbl11" style="display:none" >
<tr><td name="businessdetail" id="businessdetail" ><strong>Business </strong>details</td></tr>
<tr><td>Contact Name:&nbsp;</td>            
<td><input id = 'businesscontact' name = 'businesscontact' type = 'text' size = '40' maxlength = '65'></td></tr></table>
<input type = "submit" name = "Button"  value = "Register" margin-bottom: .5em" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about the inconsistency issue after you submit the form, ex: you select the 2nd radio button '**babysitter**' and submit the form, then you found the 2nd radio button is checked while table **bustbl1** is displayed instead of **bustbl11**.

You'll need another script to be called once user enter the page to initial the page with the correct status.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function (){ 
    var isFirstItemSelected = document.getElementById('aupair').checked;
    if(isFirstItemSelected)
        selbustbla(2); // display 'bustbl1' table and hide another one
    else
        selbustbla(1); // display 'bustbl11' table and hide another one
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi this is not quite the solution because if there are more than 2 radio buttons, then it does not solve the problem.  Sorry